# Should one use multithreading or multiprocessing to send emails using smtplib python module?

Tags: python

I would like to send emails using `smtplib` concurrently. Although email sending as such is obviously an I/O-bound operation, I discovered that `smtplib` does a lot of stuff in plain python, hence I doubt that `threading` module is an appropriate choice for this due to GIL.

Should I use multiprocessing to reduce an impact of GIL?

Comment: Multithreading should be enough as most time will be consumed waiting for network response.

Comment: what's a GIL again? sorry , I always sucked at math class

Comment: @rv.kvetch [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock)